# Why does xdg-open text_file differ from sudo -u me xdg-open text_file?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, root, mime-types, xdg-open

If I run the following command, the text file opens in my preferred editor (kate).

```
$ xdg-open text_file
```

However, if I try the following, where `sparhawk` is my username, I get several warnings, and the jbidwatcher opens instead.

```
$ sudo -u sparhawk xdg-open text_file
```

What is the difference?

---

### Background

I have a script triggered by udev that will hence run as root. I'm attempting to open a log file using the user's default editor.

Here is some more output that might be helpful.

```
$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
kate.desktop
$ sudo -u sparhawk xdg-mime query default text/plain
jbidwatcher.desktop
$ sudo -iu sparhawk xdg-mime query default text/plain
jbidwatcher.desktop
$ sudo -Eu sparhawk xdg-mime query default text/plain
kate.desktop
$ sudo -iEu sparhawk xdg-mime query default text/plain
jbidwatcher.desktop
```

I also attempted testing after `sudo -i`. In all cases, the output was `jbidwatcher.desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` changes environment.

Try

`printenv` and `sudo -u sparhawk printenv` to see the difference.

Comment: Yes, they are different, but what is the specific variable that determines which programs are used for `xdg-open`?